# Как преобразовать json в spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Есть такого типа json:

```
[ {'count': 308,
  'next': 'some_url',
  'previous': None,
  'results': [{'assigned_to': 43,
    'category': 'Unused',
    'comments': None,
    'completed_ts': None,
    'created': '2019-05-27T05:14:22.306843Z',
    'description': 'Pollution',
    'display_name': {'admin': False,
     'business_name': 'Test Business',
     'contact_number': 'some_number',
     'dob': None,
     'email': 'some_mail',
     'emp_id': None,
     'first_name': 'Alisha'}}]},
  {'count': 309,
  'next': 'some_url',
  'previous': None,
  'results': [{'assigned_to': 44,
    'category': 'Unused',
    'comments': None,
    'completed_ts': None,
    'created': '2019-05-27T05:14:22.306843Z',
    'description': 'Pollution',
    'display_name': {'admin': False,
     'business_name': 'Test Business',
     'contact_number': 'some_number',
     'dob': None,
     'email': 'some_mail',
     'emp_id': None,
     'first_name': 'Ali'}}]},......}]
```

Необходимо преобразовать его в dataframe

Comment: `spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("filename")` ?

Comment: Проблема в том, что это не совсем json, это полученные с помощью api данные

Comment: Можно создать RDD со строками, и прочитать его как JSON. Например вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59268223/18627

Answer (score 0):

В общем для себя открыл такое решение:

```
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json.dumps(data)]))
```